# How to create link with article Id in news(tx_news) in typo3?

Tags: typo3-6.2.x, tx-news

I have article  with `uid` **xyz** and `pid` **foobar** . How to create a link for the detail page using `f:uri.action` or `f:link.page` (or any other uri) outside `news` extension?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To answer the question to 100%, the links can be built by using

**`<f:link.page />`**

```
<f:link.page 
  pageUid="13" 
  additionalParams="{tx_news_pi1: {controller: 'News',action: 'detail', news:newsItem.uid}}">
    {newsItem.title}
</f:link.page>
```

**`<f:uri.page />`**

```
<a 
    href="{f:uri.page(
        pageUid:13,
        additionalParams:'{tx_news_pi1:{controller:\'News\',action:\'detail\',news:newsItem.uid}}')}">
    {newsItem.title}
</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also take the `f:link.action` ViewHelper

```
<f:link.action pageUid="{settings.detailPid}" extensionName="News" pluginName="pi1" controller="News" action="detail" arguments="{news:newsItem.uid}" >
{newsItem.title}
</f:link.action>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<f:link.page pageUid="{settings.detailPid}" additionalParams="{
             tx_news_pi1:{news:newsItem.uid,controller:'News',action:'detail'}
             }"> Detail Link </f:link.page>
```

Just change standard vars on your.